Transition on a Pagination in React
I try to style button which is active in that way that I have a small transition on it when it gets that attribute but I can't get it. Same on the paragraph which is being rendered from the data file
function Pagination() {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);

    function TabButton({ children, handleClick, index }) {
        return (
            <li><button active={selected === index ? "true" : "false"} onClick={handleClick}>{children}</button></li>
        );
    }

    function handleClick(index) {
        setSelected(index);
    }

    return (
        <div className="pagination-container">
                <div className="pagination-right">
                    <h3>Discover New Horizon</h3>
                    <div className="headers">
                        <ul>
                            <TabButton index={0} handleClick={() => handleClick(0)}>about us</TabButton>
                            <TabButton index={1} handleClick={() => handleClick(1)}>why choose us</TabButton>
                            <TabButton index={2} handleClick={() => handleClick(2)}>our mission</TabButton>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div className='paragraph'>
                        <p>
                            {pagins[selected].content}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

.headers button {
    border: 0;
    color: #9b9b9b;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #9b9b9b;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.headers button[active="true"] {
    color: var(--primary-color);
    border-color: var(--primary-color);
}

.headers button:hover {
    color: var(--primary-color);
}

.paragraph {
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

I change active when there is a match between index and selected and when I have an active attribute on a button I change a color on it with its border but it happens straightaway without transition on hover transition works but not on that

Problem :
attributes are recognised using data-* pattern not directly as you mentioned active attribute in the <button>.

active is not valid attribute for button.
More about data-* here in the docs
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*

Solution:
Better to use ClassName instead. I am just adding className here with same logic.
function TabButton({ children, handleClick, index }) {
    return (
        <li>
            <button 
                className={selected === index ? "active" : ""} 
                onClick={handleClick}
            >
                {children}
            </button>
        </li>
    );
}

CSS
.headers button {
    border: 0;
    color: #9b9b9b;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #9b9b9b;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.headers button.active {
    color: var(--primary-color);
    border-color: var(--primary-color);
}

.headers button:hover {
    color: var(--primary-color);
}

.paragraph {
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

